# Thread or Timer , The best way for running every x minute

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, task

I Have at least 20 threads that each does some operations every x minutes. My issue here is that I can use timers with interval, which I register a delegate on their ElapsedEventHandler and in that method I do my operation with Thread or Task . BTW I can manage timer's start, stop and interval easily

Is this the best way ? 
Is there any other solution or other choices in .NET?

for example :

```
List<IpeTimer> Timers = new List<IpeTimer>();

        Timers.Add(new IpeTimer(){ TimerName = "timer1" ,Timer = new System.Timers.Timer()});
        Timers[0].Timer.Interval = 4000;
        Timers[0].Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerEventProcessor1);
        Timers[0].Timer.Start();


        Timers.Add(new IpeTimer() { TimerName = "timer2", Timer = new System.Timers.Timer() });
        Timers[1].Timer.Interval = 5000;
        Timers[1].Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerEventProcessor2);
        Timers[1].Timer.Start();
```

and

```
public static void TimerEventProcessor1(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task t2 = new Task(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
        }
        , TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        t2.Start();
    }

    public static void TimerEventProcessor2(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task t2 = new Task(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2");
        }
        , TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        t2.Start();
    }
```

Comment: As best I understand what you are asking, I would set up the timer and inside its event handler would fire the 20 Tasks or Threads.  I would use Tasks but I cannot argue that it's any better than Threads.  I don't know.  I have no idea how else to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the above.

Use an async method that awaits a `Task.Delay` (which internally uses a `Threading.Timer`). That way the interval you wait will not depend on how long the operation takes (i.e. if the timer's interval is 2 seconds but it takes 1 second to run there will only be a second in which no operation runs):

```
async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // do something
        await Task.Delay(1000, token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution by using your code.

```
    public static CancellationToken Token { get; private set; }
    public static void Cancel()
    { 
        Token = new CancellationToken(true);
    }

    async static Task DoSomething(int interval)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            await Task.Delay(interval, Token);
        }
    }


    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoSomething(1000);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Cancel();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```